# Windows IoT Remote Client tool not connecting with Dragonboard410c

Tags: iot

I tried windows IoT Client application with the Dragonboard410c but it is not working, Any one have any idea how it can be connected.

Answer (score 3):

First, check your pi network connection, make sure it's reachable from your host PC. It's either Pi and PC and connected to the same network, or you directly connect Pi to PC with an Ethernet cable.

Check your Remote server settings, chances are you're not enabling the "Windows IoT Remote Server".

I've seen it myself several times.

Log in to the admin web page, on the very bottom of the left tabs, go to "Remote", and check if your "Enable Windows IoT Remote Server" checkbox is really checked.

[image]

Comment: And i have also get a problem , when remote client is connected when client screen is not visualize but keyboard mouse is working.

Answer (score 2):

I just solved this problem for myself so I thought I would let anyone who might have the same problem know.

I started by updating visual studio, It looks like making sure your .net framework is the ticket.

I updated to Visual Studio Update 3
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2015-update3-vs

it took a long time, I think I read you need at least Update 1.

Once I completed the update it connected using the default setting not the IP address. Make sure the Ip is not included in the lower box of win IOT remote client

There are also other steps you might need to take including

- Using Powershell to add the device as a trusted device
  https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/powershell
- As well as adding taking the step in the comment above.

Good luck - Windows IOT on pi has a pit of a learning curve